# Where does "Burnside's Advice" come from?

Tags: story-identification

Everyone can quote 'Burnside's Advice'...

> "Friends Don't Let Friends Use Reactionless Drives In Their Universes"

... but tracking down the original and seeing it in context is proving impossible. **Can anyone show where this famous quote originates?**

Comment: Don't know, but it must post-date Larry Niven's Known Space books and stories (published over the late 1960s to 1990s), which is likely the source of the idea that such advice was needed.

Comment: Just did a good-effort Google; it appears Ken Burnside is a game designer, and is still alive -- may even have a Facebook page.  Try messaging him?

Comment: Yeah I've trawled through that Ken Burnside's work and couldn't find anything, might be worth contacting him anyway I suppose.

Comment: You could twit at him; https://twitter.com/kenburnside1?lang=en

Comment: @Valorum Thanks for that, if ever I take leave of my senses sufficient to twit  at all I'll look him up.

Comment: @Ash Please share the answer here if you find out.

Comment: Yes, Burnside's Advice is from Ken Burnside. I think he first posted it on the Yahoo Group sfconsim-l. I have contacted him and brought this question to his attention.

Comment: The basic problem is that reactionless drives are so efficient that one can make a dirt-cheap planet-cracking missile by mounting one in the equivalent of a Naval row boat.

Comment: @Ash Don't worry, I've been absent from my senses for a while now, [thereyago](https://twitter.com/IamMooz/status/910689395006566403)

Comment: @WinchellChung But what if the reactionless drive costs more than a planet?  Hmmm...

Comment: @ZeissIkon Unless they cost more than another way of destroying a planet in a single blow the problem stands.

Comment: @JDoe Did you see that the answer has been posted?

Comment: @Ash WTF? I have no memory of this place.

Comment: @Ash But man, great 5-year follow-up!

Comment: @JDoe I hadn't seen your comment when I was last here but came back to this question for some reason and spotted it so thought I'd better check.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I'm the [Ken Burnside](http://www.adastragames.com) in question.

It came up in response to a reoccuring discussion on [SFCONSIM-L](https://groups.yahoo.com/neo/groups/sfconsim-l/info), a mailing list I moderate (and participated actively in at the time as I was developing Attack Vector: Tactical).

> **New List Member:**  *"Hi, I'm writing about X, with spaceships that do multiple G thrusts, just like in the works of author Y!"*
>
> **Ken (and other list members):**  *"How do you keep someone from sterilizing planets as a result of putting that multiple G thrust on a
>   cruise missile, launching it from the orbit of Saturn and letting it
>   hit at fractions of c?  The only way to really avoid this is using
>   delta-v limited thrust and the rocket equation."*
>
> **New List Member:**  *"You big meany!  I'm just trying to tell stories of rip-roaring adventure!  If it's good enough for author Y,
>   it's HARD SF!"*
>
> ***Ken:***  "Author Y made their reputation {30|40|50} years ago, and standards have changed.  Besides, reaction drive calculations can be
>   done fairly simply with a spreadsheet.  You will end up with
>   multi-month travel times, going onwards of two years, which may impact
>   the story you want to tell."
>
> **New List Member:** *"AAARGH! You're ∗impossible!"∗*
>
> **Ken:**  *"Here's my advice: **Friends don't let friends use reactionless drives in their universes."***

This happened multiple times over four years, and *Burnside's Advice* became the shorthand form of the discussion. I'm still amused that this gets quoted more than 15 years later!

Comment: For what it is worth, I can vouch for the Ken Burnside who answered above. But do you trust me? I quote Ken in my website: http://www.projectrho.com/public_html/rocket/reactionlessdrive.php

Comment: Just replied on Twitter.

Comment: Ok, [confirmation received](https://twitter.com/IamMooz/status/910689395006566403). This is the _real_ Ken Burnside people :). See also: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ifezW.jpg

Comment: An excellent answer. I've taken the liberty of editing the text into a block for readability.

Comment: "I'm still amused that this gets quoted more than 15 years later!"  Clarke's Law is three times that age, maybe more.  Murphy (of Murphy's Law) was a real rocket scientist at White Sands in the 1940s, an acquaintance of G. Harry Stine.  Burnside's advice will probably still be quoted when interplanetary travel, at least, is no longer SF.

Comment: @WinchellChung I know that's where I saw it most recently.

Comment: @KenBurnside Do you know of a list with other technologies that break the way the world works in strange ways? I've read a couple of essays on travelling in time and space lately that seemly to alluded to a list of technologies that sound good until you look too close, your advice was quoted along with similar admonishments concerning time travel and inertial dampers.